# How to add Power Bi second line to "line and stacked column chart"?

Tags: powerbi

In Power Bi Desktop version I can not add a second line when I used "line and stacked column chart". I added to 2 variable to the column chart. Is it related with Power Bi version or there is a constraint in Power Bi? How to solve this problem?

Thanks your help.

Comment: You can only add one line in a combo chart.